# Having error (all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id') in django

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make **API** with Django REST framework

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.eventList, name="events"),
    path('detail/<str:pk>/', views.eventDetail, name="detail"),
    path('create', views.eventCreate, name="create"),
    path('update/<str:pk>/', views.eventUpdate, name="update"),
    path('delete/<str:pk>/', views.eventDelete, name="delete")
]
```

views.py:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def eventList(request):
    events = Orders.objects.all()
    serializer = OrdersSerializer(events, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
def eventDetail(request, pk):
    events = Orders.objects.all(id=pk)
    serializer = OrdersSerializer(events, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

And when i want to access to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events/detail/1/` Gives that error. But `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events/` still working.

And also I did not find the right solution in my search for this error

p.s. I make my *models.py* with **inspectdb**

Comment: Did you try ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/detail/1/```

Comment: @FloLie I have tried this But it doesn't work because i haven't generate this link.

Comment: Side note, reimplementing all CRUD views manually kinda loses the whole point of using django-rest-framework.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Do you have any suggestion? Because I'm new to Django

Comment: You should look into [view classes](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#views) in django rest framework. "CREATE", "UPDATE" and "DELETE" should not be part of the URL but a HTTP methods sent on a single URL (which django rest framework does for you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the **id=pk** from the Order queryset in eventDetail view.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def eventDetail(request, pk):
    events = Orders.objects.all() # here
    # or in case you need to filter by pk
    events = Orders.objects.filter(pk=pk)

    serializer = OrdersSerializer(events, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```